# java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC1227: Cannot forward after response has been committed.....why it was comming?

Tags: java, exception, jsp

to add some row data into a table, affter submmiting the button i have to show the details(data) in the next page of that regarding table. when i am using `RequestDispather` class i am getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException:`........ it was also comming while using `response.sendRedirect("View.jsp");`..... i am sending the code what i used in my page.

```
if(msg.equals("Values Added")){
                 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("View.jsp");
                 rd.forward(request, response);
                 }
```

(OR)

```
if(msg.equals("Values Added")){
                 response.sendRedirect("View.jsp");
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not true per se:

"You cannot change the response like that from inside a JSP. It's too late then."

Just place your postback check and redirect before the html tag in your jsp...then everything will be fine.

So:

```
<% if(msg.equals("Values Added")){
             response.sendRedirect("View.jsp");
             } %>
```

`<html > ... </html>`

Answer (score 3):

JSP is part of the response. You cannot change the response like that from inside a JSP. It's too late then. This piece of code should have been placed in a servlet class.

Change your form to submit to a servlet instead:

```
<form action="servleturl" method="post">
```

Create a servlet class which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/servleturl/*` and move all the Java code you have there in JSP into the `doPost()` method.

#### See also:

- [Servlets tag info page - mini tutorial and useful links](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Sorry i my project we not using servlets presentation and bussiness.. only for ajax.

Comment: JSP is the wrong place for business. JSP is for presentation only. Servlet is for business. Report it to your manager. If he disagree, then you have two options: 1) Bad luck, live with it, do it all in a single large JSP with lot of conditional includes instead. 2) Look for a better job where there are no stupid restrictions like that.

Comment: very simple and helpful explanation +1

Comment: Sorry..!u miss understood my comment. we r developing in the bussiness in seperate layer total the project bulid by spring hibernate with Desing pattern............!

Comment: I think you misunderstood how a well designed JSP/Servlet/Spring/Hibernate web application look like.

Answer (score 0):

use else if in place of if

Comment: their was no chance to else because before that some Service method was executing it was returning String value(which was storing on msg variable) depending on that message only i have to show the next page........... Thanks for u reply...! can u send any thing else